# Resize a table with formulas based on user input

Tags: excel, vba

I want resize a table in my worksheet depending on the input form a user.

Example: In cell A1 the user enters 55, I then want the table (Table1) in the worksheet sheet1 to expand form cell B1 to F55 with formatting and formulas.

I have the following code to expand the table, but the formulas do no expand.

```
Sub test()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim value As Range
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ent = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")

Set wkb = Workbooks("SoD Template.xlsm")

With wkb
    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

sh1.Select
    
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

 Set rng = Range("Table1[#All]").Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + value, tbl.Range.Columns.Count)

  tbl.Resize rng

End With

End Sub
```

I was thinkinking to use `LastRow` function to find the last formula and then copy this down.

Additionally I want to have the option that if the user enters a new range in cell A1, of example 45, the table and formatting plus formulas extend to 45, the rest of the table and formulas are deleted.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tables DO resize themselves automatically AFAIK

Comment: Yes, when you enter data in a new row or column. However, I want to give the user the option to enter the number of rows on a different sheet (in a later process) and then have the exact number of rows + formulas ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables are supposed to fill the formulas automatically when rows are expanded.

So maybe recreating the table would fix the issue and checking the fill formulas in table in the autocorrection options `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False` ([check this](https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/prevent-table-formula-autofill/)).

In case you have gaps in columns with formulas and would like to fill the whole column with the same formula, check the following code, read the comments, and adjust it to fit your needs.

**Code**

```
Public Sub ResizeTable()
    
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
    
    ' Set the target sheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheetName As String
    targetSheetName = "Sheet1"
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetSheetName)
    
    ' Get new rows number from cell
    Dim newTableRows As Long
    Dim newTableRowsCellAdd As String
    newTableRowsCellAdd = "A1"
    newTableRows = targetSheet.Range(newTableRowsCellAdd).Value2

    ' Set the target table
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Dim targetTableName As String
    targetTableName = "Table1"
    Set targetTable = targetSheet.ListObjects(targetTableName)

    ' Resize the table
    Dim newTableRange As Range
    Set newTableRange = targetTable.Range.Resize(newTableRows + 1, targetTable.Range.Columns.Count)
    targetTable.Resize newTableRange
    
    ' Copy formulas in new rows
    Dim tableCell As Range
    Dim rowWithFormulas As Long
    rowWithFormulas = 1
    For Each tableCell In targetTable.ListRows(rowWithFormulas).Range
    
        If tableCell.HasFormula Then
        
            tableCell.Copy targetTable.ListColumns(tableCell.Column).DataBodyRange
        
        End If
    
    Next tableCell
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Glad it helped. I try to give to my answers more detail so people can customize them and  have more control to improve them. TinMan's answer is pretty neat though.

Answer (score 2):

The formulas will automatically fill.

```
Sub AddMultipleRowsToListObject(ListObject As ListObject, NumberOfRows As Long)
    With ListObject
        If NumberOfRows < .ListRows.Count Then
            If .ListRows.Count > 0 Then .DataBodyRange.Delete
            .Resize .HeaderRowRange.Resize(NumberOfRows + 1)
        Else
            .Resize .Range.Resize(.ListRows.Count + NumberOfRows)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: I edited my answer so that the `ListObject` will automatically delete any extra rows when resized.